# How to post to my own timeline/page without requesting publish_actions and manage_pages permissions?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a blog website and I have a Facebook page where I would like to share updates from my blog. I also would like to share those updates to my personal profile/timeline. I made an application and requested the publish_actions and manage_pages permissions.

It got rejected with the following comment:

> You do not need to request these permissions because your blog or CMS
>   is integrated with an app that you admin. **As an App admin, you can
>   already access these permissions and post to your Timeline or a page
>   you admin**. You can provide access to additional users by adding them
>   as developers of your App.”

Yes, I am an admin on website, app and Facebook profile/page.

But, can anyone tell me what does it mean?

I read documentation several times. It's pretty clear that I can post even to my own only with access_token. I can get access token if I ask for authorization.

If a request authorization with publish_actions, manage_pages authorization dialog comes with the red banner saying:

> *"The following permissions have not been approved for use and are not being shown to people using your app: publish_actions and
>   manage_pages.Submit them for review or learn more."*

and

> "This does not let the app post to Facebook."

. Then any attempt to post comes with *Error #200) The user hasn’t authorized the application to perform this action.* It I don't ask for permission I just getting Error 200.

So how exactly I can "already access these permissions and post to my Timeline or a page I admin" as an App admin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that around mid May they of went back on the review process, at least partially; if your user owns the app and the page then you should be able to publish to your stream or to your page without going through the review process... I guess you just don't have to ask for the permissions that triggers the review process.

I'll be testing this in a bit and I'll get back to you with my results.

UPDATE: Yup. I've just tested it... just ask for publish_actions, manage_pages and status_update and it'll let you autopost on your own page, just ignore the warning about the review process.

Comment: If you want to posting on facebook using ios sdk. Please remove the bundle Id from facebook manage app.and then post... and just ignore the warning about the review process.